# Rails controller params undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a simple api on Rails. (v4.1.8)
However, it seems like the parameters that I send never reach the controller.
I always get:

```
undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass
```

The controller code is:

```
class API::V1::ServiceController < ApiBaseController
  def initialize
    puts 'OK. I am here.' # <---- I can get here without error.
    puts params.inspect # <---- Here is where the error occur.
    render json: {message: 'Test completed.'}
  end
end
```

ApiBaseController is nothing:

```
class ApiBaseController < ActionController::Base

end
```

Route:

```
namespace :api , :defaults => {:format => :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    get 'initialize',       to: 'service#initialize'
  end
end
```

My test URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/initialize?param1=one
```

Comment: Which line throws this error? This type of error is thrown when you call a method on a `nil` object. In this case, at some point you are doing `@some_object.parameters`, but `@some_object` is `nil`

Comment: When I try to access "params" as you can see in the controller code I put a marker there.

Comment: I think the problem is with the method name `initialize`. In ruby `initialize` method denotes the constructor. Try renaming the method.

Comment: @Santhosh Yes, I think that is the cause. I changed to initialize_system and error is gone. Maybe you can answer it and I'll mark it as answer. Is there a reference link to all the reserved method name?

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added 2 reference links in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is due to the use of `initialize` as an action name. In Ruby, `initialize` is a keyword, denoting the class constructor. In this case, params is getting called before the controller class is initialized, and hence the error.

Refer [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Instantiation-And-The-Initialize-Method.htm) for more information about the `initialize` keyword, and this [list of all ruby keywords](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm).